# vb.net ComboBox Text Changing When Left

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I'm having an issue with my ComboBoxes whereby if I type into it to get a value & then tab out the Text changes to the first item in the list with the first letter typed.

I have:

- AutoCompleteMode set to SuggestAppend
- AutoCompleteSource set to ListItems
- DropDownStyle set to DropDownList

I add the items for the ComboBox in the Load event of the Form the ComboBox is on.

e.g. the below is code from a Load event where I populate a ComboBox that I have set up as below.

```
   `Me.ComboBox1.Text = ""
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("a")
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("aaa")
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("combo")
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("combobox")
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("combobox test")
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("common")
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("common dialog")`
```

After running the code, if I select the ComboBox1 & type in common - common is selected in ComboBox1 but if I leave ComboBox1 the Text reverts to combo.

It gets a bit stranger as if I user the below code in the ComboBox1_Leave event procedure it throws common:

`MsgBox(ComboBox1.Text)`

I've also tried assigning the value of Text to a string in the ComboBox1_KeyUp event procedure & then assign that to ComboBox1.Text in the ComboBox1_Leave event procedure but that doesn't do anything.

If I put a the above MsgBox code before assigning the strings value to ComboBox1.Text then the Text value does revert to Common but this is isn't a practical solution.

I've also noticed that if I hit Enter before hitting tab it retains the correct value but again I'm don't think this is a particularly practical solution.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here & how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely necessary to have the DropDownStyle set to DropDownList?

Because if you set `DropDownStyle to DropDown` the selected value will be retained when you press tab or lose the focus.

If it's absolutely necessary to have it that way, you could try this.

```
Public Class Form2

  Dim selectedTextForCombo As String = ""

  Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.ComboBox1.Text = ""
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("a")
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("aaa")
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("combo")
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("combobox")
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("combobox test")
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("common")
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("common dialog")
  End Sub

  Private Sub ComboBox1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.LostFocus
    ComboBox1.SelectedItem = selectedTextForCombo
    'This is just for a visualization of your issue
    'Label1.Text = selectedTextForCombo
  End Sub

  Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    selectedTextForCombo = ComboBox1.Text
    'This is just for a visualization of your issue
    'Label1.Text = selectedTextForCombo
  End Sub

End Class
```

Warning:

- This example works with the tab action.
- If the users writes something that doesn't exist like "commun" the
  selected value will end up being the visually selected value, in this
  case: "common"

Comment: Thanks a mill Koken, this works! I didn't realise that it worked for DropDown as DropDown style but in any event I need it to be DropDownList for some of my ComboBoxes as I need the user to select from a defined list.

Comment: @jbmb2000 Glad it worked for you. You know, I wouldn't advise using "DropDownList" if the user can write to search for an option. I recommend you to use that option when the list of options aren't that big so the user can select an option easily instead of searching for one.

Comment: any particular reason for that? I've previously used VBA & only relatively new to vb.net so still very much at the base of the mountain in terms of understanding it & the differences between it & VBA.

Comment: Not a heavy reason at all, it's just because of user experience for me.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll keep an eye on it & see if I get any complaints. I don't really like leaving it open to manual entries though as alot of my combo boxes need to have one of the listed entries selected - alot of stuff pulls data from a SQL database based on the selection.

Comment: I think you should do what suits best for you, don't worry to much of my advise, the most important thing is what your users tells you about that :D .

Comment: :-D - thanks again for your help, it has really helped & will mean less banging of my head off the walls! Have a good weekend!